# IIS 7 W3C logs not logging call to .asmx

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, asmx

I have a page call it 'Service.asmx' that I'm trying to research via IIS (W3C) logs.   However all traffic to that page does not appear in the logs.

Here are  a few things to note:

1. All other traffic to the site does seem to appear in the log
2. other .asmx services in the same directory and application pool appear successfully in the log
3. All requests to the service result in 200 OK
4. Other traffic to the site with 200 OK shows successfully in the log
5. even though other hits within the application pool are successful I attempted to add the user associated with the pool to the local admins group.   This did not result in a change.

I've wondered many times if I was looking in the correct log instance, however, by adding a custom response header and calling via a browser I'm sure I'm looking at the correct log as well.

I've seen several articles online referencing `<httpLogging>` configuration that might affect a single page, but I've full-text searched all *.config instances on the server and have found no references to this tag set at all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.